# Apache Proxy pass for static file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I would like to serve same file(`/app/index.html`) for all path request path(`/app/**/*.*`) in same & `/app/index.html` is present in same Apache server itself, not sure how to setup proxy pass for this scenario in `httpd.conf` file. Need help in adding proxy rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need simple RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/app/(.*)/ /app/index.html
```

Comment: wouldn't this loop? It is redirecting over itself

Comment: The conditon has trailing slash

Comment: Can ProxyPassMatch achieve the same thing?